# liboping ошибка operation not permitted

Tags: c++, linux, qt, lib

написал такую функцию, использовал liboping linux, выдает ошибку, может кто знает как фиксить

```
        QString msg;

        pingobj_t *pingobj = ping_construct();

        if (pingobj == nullptr)
          {
            msg = "Error: ";
            msg += ping_get_error(pingobj);
          }
          ui->textEdit->setText(msg);

        int timeout = 3;
        for (;;)
          {
            double timeout_sec = ((double)timeout)/(double)(1000.0);

            if (ping_setopt(pingobj, PING_OPT_TIMEOUT, &timeout_sec))
              break;

            if (ping_host_add(pingobj, ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str()))
              break;

            if (ping_send(pingobj) <= 0)
              break;

            res = true;

            break;
          }


        if(res)
          ui->textEdit->setText("Yes");
        else
          {
            msg = "Error: ";
            msg += ping_get_error(pingobj);
            ui->textEdit->setText(msg);
          }

        ping_destroy(pingobj);
```

Comment: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/7687987

Comment: здравствуйте, использую qt каждому файлу проекта раздал права, но всё равно ошибка, она же наверно создаёт объектный файл и его запускает, у которого нет прав. как это поправить ?

Comment: @DanBit, наверное надо обратиться к системному администратору

Comment: https://github.com/octo/liboping/issues/43

Comment: не  понимаю как там решается проблемам ?

Comment: Обычно такие ошибки возникают, если нет доступа к какому-либо внешнему ресурсу: файлу, порту. Может мешать файервол, или порт закрыт для вашего сервиса и так далее

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб работал пинг - ему надо дать разрешения для прямого доступа к сетевому стеку.

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep myping
```

После компиляции выполни эту команду для запускаемого файла и пинг заработает.

В SDK можно добавить шаг сборки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дал файлу /opt/oping/bin/oping root и прописал от рута setcap cap_net_raw=ep /opt/oping/bin/oping не заработало. Добавил в SDK (написал как у вас) сборка не завершается. Не знаю что теперь делать...

Comment: Сдк собирает сразу в опт?

Comment: Опт ? Вот настроил сборку как у вас, выбираю отладку, и всё ничего не происходит проэкт не запускается ошибки не выдает

Comment: Ошибки на сборке не?

Comment: нет именно ошибок нет и в коде их нет, проблема ток с правами

Comment: сбросил скриншот